# How can I add a force to object each time to a random position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
rb.AddForceAtPosition(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime,
                        transform.position);
```

rb is Rigidbody

Lines 66-67.

but when I'm running the game the object starts rolling and moving each time to the same direction and position/s.

The force on the start is all the time make the object roll and move to the same place/s.

The first force should be pushing the object to the forward(right) but then I want it to keep rolling to random places but it's moving to the same place.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rolling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NaviManager naviManager;
    public float speed;
    public float timeToStopRolling;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public string onCollisionState;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private bool isTouching = false;
    private bool stopRollingCoroutine = false;
    private bool stopRolling = false;

    public float slowdownStartTimer = 0f;
    public float waitBeforeSlowdown = 2f;

    public float startDrag;
    public float endDrag = 50;

    public float lerpTimer = 0.0f;
    public float lerpTimeMultiplicator = 0.25f;

    private Quaternion defaultRotation;
    private bool rotateToDefault = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        startDrag = rb.drag;

        defaultRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rotateToDefault)
        {
            var step = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,
                defaultRotation, step);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (naviManager.crateOpenOnce)
        {
            if (isTouching)
            {
                if(stopRollingCoroutine == false)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(WaitBeforeStopRolling());

                    stopRollingCoroutine = true;
                }

                if (stopRolling == false)
                {
                    rb.AddForceAtPosition(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime,
                        transform.position);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (slowdownStartTimer >= waitBeforeSlowdown)
                    {
                        lerpTimer += Time.deltaTime * lerpTimeMultiplicator;
                        rb.drag = Mathf.Lerp(startDrag, endDrag, lerpTimer);

                        rotateToDefault = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        slowdownStartTimer += Time.deltaTime;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rb.velocity = rb.velocity * 0.95f * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Crate_0_0")
        {
            onCollisionState = "Touching !!!";

            isTouching = true;
        }

        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Stair")
        {
            speed = 100;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitBeforeStopRolling()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStopRolling);

        stopRolling = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you pass in the same value everytime .. how do you expect it to behave differently? Note that in general it is pretty useless to explicitly use `AddForceAtPosition` if you are using the `transform.position` anyway .. why not simply use `AddForce` ? And well if you want to randomize the direction of the force try to be more specific: When should a new random direction be chosen? How exactly do you want to randomize e.g. in any 3D direction? Only on the XZ plane? etc

Comment: @derHugo The randomize should be on the start on the first add force boost then it should keep rolling and moving on the terrain according to the terrain physics/heights. I only want the first time when it exits the box to exit in another direction then continue natural on the terrain. I did it will stop after X seconds and that's fine but I want that if it will stop then each time in another position on the terrain and not the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general to pick a random direction you could use [`Random.insideUnitCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html) and store it like e.g.

```
private Vector3 currentDirection;

public void ChoseNewRandomDirection()
{
    var rnd = Random.insideUnitCircle;
    currentDirection = new Vector3(rnd.x, 0, rnd.y). normalized;
}
```

or you could use [`Random.insideUnitSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitSphere.html) like e.g.

```
public void ChoseNewRandomDirection()
{
    var rnd = Random.insideUnitSphere;
    rnd.y = 0;
    currentDirection = rnd.normalized;
}
```

When exactly you want to call this is up to you. Probably the moment you set `isTouching` to `true`.

And then later use that in

```
rb.AddForce(currentDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

One further side note: Instead of all your flags in `FixedUpdste` why not use the Coroutine itself together with [`WaitForFixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForFixedUpdate.html) and do all the rolling etc directly there instead?

This way you could better control it and it would be clearer and easier to maintain exactly which case is entered when.

Something like

```
private bool alreadyRolling;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //NOTE: In general you should go for Tags instead of the name
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Crate_0_0")
    {
        if (naviManager.crateOpenOnce)
        {
            // Directly start a routine here (if none is already running)
            if(!alreadyRolling) StartCoroutine (RollingRoutine());  
        }
    }

    ...
}

private Vector3 GetRandomDirection()
{
    var rnd = Random.insideUnitSphere;
    rnd.y = 0;
    return rnd.normalized;
}

private IEnumerator RollingRoutine ()
{
    // Just in case prevent concurrent routines
    if(alreadyRolling) yield break;

    // Block new routines from starting
    alreadyRolling = true;

    // Get the random direction for this routine
    var rollDirection = GetRandomDirection();

    // Roll for the given time within the FixedUpdate call
    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < timeToStopRolling; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        // Wait until you are in FixedUpdate
        // the code after this is now executed within FixedUpdate
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

        rb.AddForce(rollDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    // Wait before slowing down
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitBeforeSlowdown);

    // Do slow down and rotate to default until both conditions are fulfilled
    var dragLerpFactor = 0f;
    // Store the original drag to reset it later
    var defaultDrag = rb.drag;
    while(!Mathf.Approximately(rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude, 0) || rb.rotation != defaultRotation)
    {
        // Again wait until you are in FixedUpdate
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate ();

        dragLerpFactor += Time.deltaTime * lerpTimeMultiplicator;
        rb.drag = Mathf.Lerp(startDrag, endDrag, dragLerpFactor);

        rb.MoveRotation( Quaternion.RotateTowards(rb.rotation, defaultRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    } 

    // Just to be sure to end with clean value assign once
    rb.rotation = defaultRotation;
    rb.drag = defaultDrag;
    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;

    // Allow the next routine to start
    alreadyRolling = false;
}
```

Something like this and as you can see you would get rid of all the `bool` flags and `FixedUpdate` and `Update`.

Comment: You're right, when isTouching is true.  I'm trying it now.

Comment: With the last edit I tested it.  At least one time so far after the object stopped rolling and moving and then rotated to the default rotation he started rolling and moving again. and a few times I tested and the object when isTouching is true he moved in the box to the left(from the player point of view). Sometimes it's moving out the box but sometimes it's moving and getting out the box from the left.